# Is it possible to to find the indexes of blacklisted dates in a sample vector of dates?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a tricky problem in R that I just can't seem to solve without resorting to a loop.

I start with a vector of timeDates:

```
library(timeDate)
dates <- timeDate(c("2014-01-01","2008-01-02","2008-01-03","2008-01-04"))
```

I would like to find the indexes of any dates in a preset blacklist:

```
dateBlacklist <- timeDate(c("2008-01-02","2008-01-03"))
```

The result would be something like:

```
indexesOfBlacklistedDates <- c(2,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly solution:

```
indexesOfBlacklistedDates <- which(timeDate:::as.character.timeDate(dates) %in% timeDate:::as.character.timeDate(dateBlacklist))
```

Another, not so ugly, solution (similar to @agstudy's answer)

```
which(as.character(dates) %in% as.character(dateBlacklist))
```

Comment: Thanks! The last solution is quite nice, in my eyes, as the intent is quite clear from the code. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Elegant solution :)

```
match(as.character(dateBlacklist), as.character(dates))
[1] 2 3
```

Comment: Ended up using the %in% answer as the intent of the code is clearer to me. Thanks anyway,  much appreciated!